# Volatile for publishing effectively immutable objects

Tags: java, multithreading, thread-safety

Would it be safe to use only `volatile` for publishing a mutable object which is never mutated?

```
class Mutable {

private int i;

Mutable(int i) {
 this.i=i;
}

int getI() {
 return i;
}

}
```

This class is accessed by multiple threads:

```
@Singleton
class Holder {

private volatile Mutable effectivelyImmutable = new Mutable(1);

int getI() {
 return effectivelyImmutable.getI();
}

void resetMutalbe(int i) {
 Mutable newMutable = new Mutable(i);
 effectivelyImmutable = newMutable;
}

}
```

Would all threads get 1 from `Holder.getI()` if `Holder.resetMutalbe()` is never called?

Would all threads get 2 from `Holder.getI()` if `Holder.resetMutalbe(2)` was called from any thread before `Holder.getI()`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, `volatile` is enough, since it creates a happens-before relationship. Writes to a volatile field happen-before reads to it, so all actions prior to calling `Holder#resetMutalbe()` are visible after calling `Holder#getI()`.

Comment: Unfortunately I couldn't quickly find the official spec quickly, but found this "the values that were visible to A before writing the volatile variable will be visible to B after reading the volatile variable" on https://www.baeldung.com/java-volatile. All the values from the `Mutable` instance are visible to thread A before writing to the volatile var, hence they are visible to any other thread after reading from the var,

Comment: @super.t They are visible to threads that read from the variable, not all threads in the JVM.